# Unable to call .py and .pyw files in IDLE Shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently downloaded Python version 3.10.2 as well as pip (version 21.3.1). I've been following a tutorial and at the point where I'm creating .py scripts. In the script itself, this is the current code:

```
print('Hello World!')
```

When I try to call the script in IDLE Shell, I get a syntax error. When I execute commands in IDLE Shell itself, everything is working perfectly fine.

I've been looking around online to see what could be the problem, and I note that there are two types of scripts which is determined by having either python.exe or pythonw.exe (correct me if I'm wrong). When I input the import sys command into Shell, this is what I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Python310\pythonw.exe
```

From my research, only .pyw scripts can be called in this case?

Either way, this is what I get when I try to call a .py or .pyw file in Shell:

```
$ python3 hello.py 
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax


$ python3 hello.pyw
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The $ is what is highlighted in red whenever the error comes up, and the script is saved as it is called.

System variable paths have been created but not a user one, and I'm not sure whether this could be potentially causing the error? I've checked a couple of tutorials on how to install python in case I had done it incorrectly, but neither mentioned anything about creating a user variable path.

I have also tried to use `python setup.py install` and `setup.py install` in cmd, but the error I get is:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\\XXXX\\XXXX\\setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

Comment: `python3` is a command you would type at your operating system's command prompt, NOT inside a running Python shell.  (And even at the command prompt, you wouldn't actually type the `$`, that's the prompt itself.)  To run a script inside IDLE, you would open it via the File menu, then select Run from whatever menu that appears in (or hit F5, I think).

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had no idea that this is how you run scripts inside IDLE.